# How can I change a View's visibility based on whether a list is empty or not

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a `List` in a model that bounds to a layout using the data-binding lib. How can I change a `View`'s visibility based on the list's `isEmpty()` condition? Something like `android:visibility="@{model.list.isEmpty() ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"`

Comment: The adapter of your listviews should be notified about the change in data by using `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

You can even try `listView.invalidate()`

Comment: @Nirel my question was about the [data-binding library](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, although it wasn't clear from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html), it can be done using [custom setters](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#custom_setters) as follows:

In my model, I had to declare

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
public static void setVisibility(View view, Model model) {

        view.setVisibility(model.getList().isEmpty() ? View.INVISIBLE: View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Then, in the layout

```
 android:visibility="@{model}"
```

where `model` is the name of the model's variable in `<variable name=""/>`

Answer (score 2):

Let's call a new file "BindingAdapters", since possibly you will be using it on other places.

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("visibleGone")
    fun showHide(view: View, show: Boolean) {
        view.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

on the XML you just have to do the following:

```
app:visibleGone="@{viewModel.list.isNotEmpty()}"
```